# if $\tan x$ is negative in quadrant 2, why is $\tan 2x$ positive in quadrant 2?

Tags: circles

$\tan x = -3,\,\sin x = \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} ,\,\cos x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{10}}$

If you work it out, $\tan 2x = \frac{3}{4}$

I don't understand how $\tan x$ is negative, but $\tan 2x$ is positive.

Comment: Please, try to use MathJax for your typing.

Comment: $2x$ is not in the 2nd quadrant, and $\tan 2x$ is not always positive when $x$ is in the 2nd quadrant, so it is not clear what the question is asking.

Comment: Just draw the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent function is positive in quadrants $1$ and $3$, and negative in quadrant $2$ and $4$ (you can get this by considering where sine and cosine are positive and negative, and then use quotient identities).
For your problem, $x$ and $2x$ are just the INPUT angle into the tangent function.  For instance, consider the angle $x=75^{\circ}$.  Since this angle is in quadrant $1$, $\tan75^{\circ}$ will be positive.  However, $2x=2\cdot 75^\circ=150^\circ$, which is in quadrant $2$, and so $\tan2x=\tan150^\circ$, will be negative.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear to me now.   I really appreciate your answer.  And now I have to figure out how to use MathJax.